# CefSharp new version IContextMenuHandler

Tags: wpf, cefsharp

[How do I hide the CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser right click context menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34244244/how-do-i-hide-the-cefsharp-winforms-chromiumwebbrowser-right-click-context-menu)

```
public class CustomMenuHandler : CefSharp.IContextMenuHandler 
{
    public void OnBeforeContextMenu(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IContextMenuParams parameters, IMenuModel model)
    {
        model.Clear();
    }

    public bool OnContextMenuCommand(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IContextMenuParams parameters, CefMenuCommand commandId, CefEventFlags eventFlags)
    {

        return false;
    }

    public void OnContextMenuDismissed(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame)
    {

    }

    public bool RunContextMenu(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IContextMenuParams parameters, IMenuModel model, IRunContextMenuCallback callback)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

previously I used the code from the above post to disable the context menu in CefSharp.
with the newest update, CefSharp.IContextMenuHandler no longer exists

how can i restore this functionality?

[image]

Comment: What is the exception you are seeing? IContextMenuHandler still exists, in fact the interface hasn't changed in over three years. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/commits/bef5dd37c4617714729042855120724279501f80/CefSharp/Handler/IContextMenuHandler.cs

Comment: added a screenshot of the errors i am getting. basically it seems the references to anything CefSharp got lost somehow. i'm guessing now this is somehow related to my project? all i did was update my nuget packages.

Comment: What version were you using? What version are you trying to upgrade to? Check the build output rather than relying on the error list. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample van be used for testing purposes.

Comment: went from v94.4.110 to v95.7.141. the build output shows all the same errors
`CustomMenuHandler.cs(13,47,13,66): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'IContextMenuHandler' does not exist in the namespace 'CefSharp' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

Comment: the cefsharp minimal example relies on .net framework 4.5.2 which i do not have installed. i tried installing both the runtime and developer pack from the ms page, and it still doesnt work. my project is targetting .net 6.0

Comment: i downgraded my nuget package to v94.4.110 and everything works again

Comment: Which Nuget package are you using?

Comment: Install-Package CefSharp.WPF

Comment: I'm surprised Nuget allowed you to upgrade. That's actually the .Net 4.5.2 package, the hacks that made it work with .Net Core and .Net 5.0+ have been removed. See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/3444 for options.

Comment: thanks much. i switched packages and its all working.